# Waiting for new page to come present, when clicking with Selenium webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I'm using Cucumber + WatirWebdriver to do some acceptance testing and I was always thinking, that the underlying webdrivers are waiting for a new page to load, after an element was clicked. I thought so, because the Firefox webdriver seems to do, what I expect. This test works flawlessly in FF, but doesn't in (for example) ghostdriver (phantomjs webdriver).

```
Scenario: Follow a link on Amazon
    When I visit Amazon
    And click your account link
    Then the title should include "Recommended"


When /^I visit Amazon$/ do
  @browser.goto "http://amazon.com"
end

When /^click your account link$/ do
  @browser.link(:id, 'nav-your-amazon').click
end

Then /^the title should include "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  @browser.title.should include arg1
end
```

I ended up, opening an issue on ghostdrivers github page and being told, that Selenium webdrivers are not intended to wait for a pageload after a click.

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click()

So now my question is, whether there is a best practice for waiting for a page to load after an action like a click?

Comment: For clarity, you should say "Given I am at Amazon" because that happens before the test starts, "When I open your account" because that is the test trigger (and I think technical details of how the account is opened can change), "Then the title should include 'Recommended'". Just my suggestion for getting the cukes right.

Comment: Thanks, but this is only a test I created to demonstrate the behavior. I don't use it anywhere :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to give you watir/Ruby code as I do all my development in Java. But the basic idea is that you want to set up a method/function to wait after your click(). Check my post on [Mink with Selenium2: follow all redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725974/mink-with-selenium2-follow-all-redirects/12730590#12730590) for an idea. The method I posted there is set up using selenium's FluentWait object to poll for an element after my click.

This is what your going to want to do:

```
.click() //click your button
.waitForElementMethod() //Fluent wait for element on page we want to wait for
//if element found continue
//else throw error
```

The doc on Fluentwait:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Good luck!